# SQL query to update serial number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database table :

```
srno | passportnumber | flightnumber
```

I need a SQL query to update the `srno` such that the `srno` is same where ever `passportnumber` is the same.

I mean if passport `abc123` and it occurs 4 times in the table then every time its serial number should be the same for all four.

Comment: Show us **your effort** ! We'll be glad to help out. Also: what if you have four rows with `passportnumber = 'abc123'` - which of those four serial numbers is going to be the one to use for all four rows??

Comment: but which of the srno is the right one - if you have more than one - which will be it ?

Comment: srno can be anything, any of the 4 can be used. It could be a random number too. Well i had no clue at all how to do this so i did not post any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE as 
(
select srno,passportnumber,flightnumbe,
row_number() over (partition by passportnumber order by (select 0)) as rnk 
from yourtable
)

update CTE set srno=rnk
```

Comment: is this T-sql? i cant get it to work on ms sql server 2005

Comment: yeah this will work in MS 2005

Comment: your query does work thanks !

Comment: You could also use rank() or dense_rank() if you wanted to avoid "holes".   Given that a random (aka arbitrary in this case) number would do the row_number() is good enough

Comment: sorry not working :( i am importing excel file into sql table , the serial number column remains null after importing file.  i am  then using your query to update the table so as to insert the serial number.

Comment: it should work for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, this should fit your needs

```
update myTable 
set srno='The SRNO' 
where passportnumber='abc123'
```

I recommend working through a basic SQL tutorial